# Why does comparing lists with %in% results in two different outputs?

Tags: r

I have run across an error while using the `%in%` operator to compare the elements of two lists.

This code can reproduce the behavior.

```
list(c(1,2)) %in% list(as.integer(c(1, 2))) # FALSE
list(c(2,2)) %in% list(as.integer(c(2, 2))) # TRUE
```

Does anyone have a clue why there are different results?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case.
We only get this special result for c(1,2).
Everything else works fine.

Comment: According to the `?"%in%"` the x and table arguments should be vector.  So, if you are passing a different structure, then unexpected things can happen

Comment: Also from `?"%in%"` "... lists are converted to character vectors" - so you essentially do `match("c(2, 2)", "c(1, 2)")` which gives `NA`. The `FALSE` is returned by `NA > 0`, which is what `%in%` does.

Comment: @markus you are right.  It is oonly for as.integer(1, 2), the return is 1:2 `as.character(list(as.integer(c(1, 2))) )#
[1] "1:2"
> as.character(list(as.integer(c(1, 3))) )#
[1] "c(1, 3)"`

Comment: @red_tank142 That is not the only case where it  returns FALSE `list(c(2,3)) %in% list(as.integer(c(2, 3)))# 
[1] FALSE` have the same issue because of the conversion

Comment: @markus Thanks a lot! That answers the question.

Comment: There is special-case code [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c499218846d14500255efd622b5021c10ec/src/main/deparse.c#L1600-L1606) that prints `m:n` for integer vectors with spacing 1 ...

Comment: could someone post an answer?